# What word/phrase to describe tough times that test a person's will?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

We all know the phrase that says something like "Tough times test a man's spirit/will." I am looking for a word that fills in the following blank and captures the essence of this phrase.

> *It is through ______ times like these that a man's spirit is truly defined.*

Comment: What words have you tried? Why didn't they fit the sentence?

Comment: Your question includes a hint for a good answer: _testing_.

Comment: @alwayslearning That's the word I'm looking for! I actually searched that up before asking this, but didn't see it on dictionary.com, but now I've checked Oxford's dictionary and see that it's there. Besides, even if it wasn't officially a word, it's gets the message clear across.

Answer (score 2):

***Difficult***

It shows that adversity does not deter a person with will power to accomplish whatever he has set out to do.

Answer (score 1):

Challenging, darkest and deepest, egregious, tough, heartbreaking, unimaginably horrific, lonely, painful...That's all I got, I'm running out of ideas. I know a quote that kinda goes with this theme, "stand in the light and be seen as we are", "be the small light in a dark room".

Comment: A song that might go with this theme is Invisible by Hunter Hayes, and Heroes by Casting Crowns.